# Fade boxes after each other in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fade in all boxes at [my site](http://tekkkz.com/) . But not like it works already. I want that first the last box fades in and then is moving down by the info box etc. so the boxes appears after each other.

The fadein effect is currently made with:

```
.content {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
    -ms-animation: fadein 3s;
    -o-animation: fadein 3s;
    animation: fadein 3s;
    background: rgba(49,54,59,0.8);
    *zoom: 1;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    75% { opacity: 0.3; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

It is possible to use jQuery, JavaScript and Css.
I hope you'll ahve a solution.

Comment: Please Refer the Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769005/how-to-make-elements-fade-after-each-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery fadeIn function (and most animations) has a "complete" option. You can pass another animation call to it  and chain them in order to achieve the proper order.

For instance, you can do:

```
$( "#box1" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
    $( "#box2" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
});
```

Comment: nah, this works:
`$(".content:hidden:last").fadeIn(1000, function() {
          $(".content:hidden:last").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $(".content:hidden:last").fadeIn(1000, function() {
          
            });
          });
        });
      });`
but can you tell me why my profile image is not loaded at the fadein?

Comment: Hm, I can see it in your first content section. Seems to work for me.

Comment: Ahh ok, its a loading bug sometimes. Btw, how can i make the "move-down" of the boxes smooth?

Comment: You can use either animate http://api.jquery.com/animate/ to change the position of the previous box before showing the new one (so, to slide it down once it alrady appeared), or instead of fading it in, you can slide it down http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`animation-delay`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp) to delay the animations so the boxes fade one after another.

```
div {
    /* Will cause animation to start after 2 second delay */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".content:hidden:last").delay(500).slideDown(1000, function() {
          $(".content:hidden:last").delay(500).slideDown(1000, function() {
            $(".content:hidden:last").delay(500).slideDown(1000, function() {
              //nothing
            });
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

For fading just replace slideDown with fadeIn

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just css using something like stagger.css

http://digitalfio.github.io/Stagger.css/

Include the css file in your `<head>`, apply the animation classes to each div then add a timing class to each div in the form of an underscore followed by an incrementing number - e.g.

```
<div class="animated slideIn _1"></div>
<div class="animated slideIn _2"></div>
<div class="animated slideIn _3"></div>
<div class="animated slideIn _4"></div>
```

so you get something like this: http://output.jsbin.com/cusuz/4